# How to change the item separator in TikZ foreach command

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, delimiters

I want to cycle over several sentences using a `foreach loop`. Now sentences will prpbably contain commas, which are used by `foreach` as item separators. So I would like to change the item separator to something that does not appear in my sentences, like e.g. `|`

So instead of

```
\foreach \x in {sentenceA,sentenceB,sentenceC}
```

I would like to use

```
\foreach \x in {sentenceA|sentenceB|sentenceC}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How about putting your sentences in braces?

Comment: I thought about that, but that wouldn't be easy to automate, as sentences may also contain dots (like in `e.g.`) where I don't want a separation. Manually putting `.|` at the end of a sentence will be much easier (or `!|` or `?|`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an `expl3` implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse,pgffor}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foreach}{ m O{,} m}
 {
  \__foreach_main:nn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__foreach_arg_seq
\clist_new:N \l__foreach_braced_clist

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__foreach_main:nn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__foreach_arg_seq { #2 } { #3 }
  \clist_clear:N \l__foreach_braced_clist
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__foreach_arg_seq
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__foreach_braced_clist { { ##1 } }
   }
  \foreach #1 in~\l__foreach_braced_clist
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Foreach{\x}[|]{sentenceA|se,nt,en,ce,B| sentenceC }{[\x]}

\Foreach{\x}{sentenceA|se,nt,en,ce,B| sentenceC }{[\x]}

\end{document}
```

The syntax is a bit different than `\foreach \x in {...}`, but this shouldn't be a big problem. The default separator is the comma, a different one can be specified in the optional argument after the variable.

[image]

Comment: How to use this `Foreach` command in the case of `\foreach [some options] \x in `. Should I add an optional <> parameter for the loop options ?

Comment: @Tarass I don't know well the options to `\foreach`.

Comment: See my proposition below. The new command does not use `foreach` itself but prepare the string to be `foreach` compatible, then you can freely use all `foreach` options.

Answer (score 11):

The comma is hardcoded in `pgffor`'s `\foreach`.
You could convert the list before and store it in a macro.
The following example puts the entries in curly braces to protect the commas.
Then initial and final spaces are also kept. In the example only an initial space is removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocommalist}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@{}
    \let\@tmp\relax
    \long\def\@tocommalist##1#2##2\@nil{%
      \ifx\@tmp\relax
        % \toks@{{##1}}% without initial trimming
        \toks@\expandafter{\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\x##1}}%
      \else
        % \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@,{##1}}% without initial trimming
        \toks@\expandafter{%
          \the\expandafter\toks@\expandafter,%
          \expandafter{\romannumeral-`\x##1}%
        }%
      \fi
      \def\@tmp{##2}%
      \ifx\@tmp\@empty
        \expandafter\@gobbletwo
      \fi
      \@tocommalist##2\@nil
    }%
    \@tocommalist#3#2\@nil
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\toks@}%
}
\makeatother

\tocommalist\mylist{|}{sentenceA|se,nt,en,ce,B| sentenceC }
\foreach \x in \mylist {%
  \typeout{[\meaning\x]}%
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in \mylist {%
  [\x]\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

Another example using package `etoolbox`. It also only trims the beginning of the entry and it removed empty entries:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etexcmds}
\DeclareListParser*{\forvertlist}{|}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vertocomma}[2]{%
  \let#1\@empty
  \forvertlist{\@verttocomma{#1}}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\@verttocomma}[2]{%
  \edef#1{%
    \ifx#1\@empty
    \else
      \etex@unexpanded\expandafter{#1},%
    \fi
    {\etex@unexpanded{#2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\vertocomma\mylist{sentenceA|| |se,nt,en,ce,B| sentenceC |}
\foreach \x in \mylist {%
  \typeout{[\meaning\x]}%
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in \mylist {%
  [\x]\par
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

When no auto-list-completion is required, *catoptions* package's `\indrisloop` can handle any list separator. The `\newforeach` macro can naturally accept any type of list separator and it can do list completion, but it is not yet on CTAN. Here is a `\indrisloop` solution. This should work even when the list separator was active. As you will notice in the result of the example, spurious spaces between the elements of the list are removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}

\begin{document}

\def\bombadil#1{%
  \typeout{Doing item: #1}%
  \edef\transformedlist{%
    \ifdefFT\transformedlist{}{\expandcsonce\transformedlist}%
    \unexpanded{\\{#1}}%
  }%
}

% \indrisloop[<separator>]{<list>}{<callback>}

\indrisloop[|]{%
  David Carlisle, item 1 |
  Heiko Oberdiek, item 2 |
  David Salomon, item 3 |
  Frank Mittelbach, item 4 |
  Donald Arseneau; item 5
}\bombadil

\show\transformedlist
\end{document}

{\show}
> \transformedlist=macro:

\\{David Carlisle, item 1}\\{Heiko Oberdiek, item 2}\\{David Salomon, item 3}
\\{Frank Mittelbach, item 4}\\{Donald Arseneau; item 5}.

l.21 \show\transformedlist
```

D.E. Knuth liked to use `\\` as a list separator.

You can transform an arbitrary list into a comma-separated list using the following `\makeintocommalist`.

```
% \makeintocommalist{<original.parser>}{<orig.list.cmd>}{<transformed.list.cmd>}

\def\makeintocommalist#1#2#3{%
  \def#3{}%
  \def\bombadil##1{%
    \edef#3{%
      \expandcsonce#3{\unexpanded{##1}}%
      \iflastindris\else,\fi
    }%
  }%
  \indrisloop*[#1]{#2}\bombadil
}
```

Example:

```
\def\alist{%
  David Carlisle, item 1 |
  Heiko Oberdiek, item 2 |
  David Salomon, item 3 |
  Frank Mittelbach, item 4 |
  Donald Arseneau; item 5 |
  Enrico Gregorio/another great |
  Ulrich Diez, yes! |
  Joseph Wright, also/+
}

\makeintocommalist{|}\alist\blist
\show\blist

> \blist=macro:->

{David Carlisle, item 1},{Heiko Oberdiek, item 2},{David Salomon, item 3},
{Frank Mittelbach, item 4},{Donald Arseneau; item 5},{Enrico Gregorio/another great},
{Ulrich Diez, yes!},{Joseph Wright, also/+}.

l.53 \show\blist
```

**EDIT**

Now I remember that the *catoptions* package has a `\cptforeach` command that does exactly what you wanted. But it doesn't do auto-completion of lists. See it in action below. It is happy with arbitrary (even weird) list item separators.

```
% \cptforeach[<optional.sep>] <holders> \in <list> \do {<callback>}

% Note the list separators in these loops:

\tikz[shading=ball]
  \cptforeach[:] \x+\cola \in 0+red : 1+green : 2+blue : 3+yellow \do {%
    \cptforeach[|] \y;\colb \in {0;red | 1;green | 2;blue | 3;yellow} \do {%
      \shade[ball color=\cola!50!\colb] (\x,\y) circle (0.4cm);
  }%
};
```

[image]

The above is equivalent to

```
\tikz[shading=ball]
  \cptforeach \x/\cola \in 0/red, 1/green, 2/blue, 3/yellow \do {%
    \cptforeach \y/\colb \in {0/red, 1/green, 2/blue, 3/yellow} \do {%
      \shade[ball color=\cola!50!\colb] (\x,\y) circle (0.4cm);
  }%
};
```

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the game, but a short and simple hack is sufficient to include both the `...` notation and coordinate parsing:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\let\pgffor@dotsscanend@original=\pgffor@dotsscanend
\def\pgffor@setdelimiter#1{%
  \def\pgffor@emptyvalues{#1 \pgffor@stop#1}%
  \def\pgffor@normal@list##1{%
    \def\pgffor@values{##1#1 \pgffor@stop#1}%
    \ifx\pgffor@values\pgffor@emptyvalues
      \def\pgffor@values{\pgffor@stop#1}%
    \fi%
    \let\pgffor@body=\pgfutil@empty%
    \global\pgffor@continuetrue%
    \pgffor@collectbody}%
  \def\pgffor@scanround(##1)##2#1{\def\pgffor@value{(##1)##2}\pgffor@scanned}%
  \def\pgffor@scanone##1#1{\def\pgffor@value{##1}\pgffor@scanned}%
  \def\pgffor@dotsscanend##1#1{\pgffor@dotsscanend@original##1,}%
}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/foreach/delimiter/.code=\pgffor@setdelimiter{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{4in} \tt
\foreach \i in {the,{quick, brown},fox,jumps,over,the,lazy,dog}{[\i]}
\\\color{red}
\foreach \i [delimiter=*] in {the*quick, brown*fox*jumps*over*the*lazy*dog}{[\i]}
\\\color{blue}
\foreach \i [delimiter=|] in {the|quick, brown|fox|jumps|over|the|lazy|dog}{[\i]}
\\\color{green}
\foreach \i [delimiter=+] in {1+...+15}{[\i]}
\\\color{purple}
\foreach \i [delimiter=!] in {(1,0)!(2,1)!(3,1)!(5,4)!(0,1)!(8,2)!(4,3)}{[\i]}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand `...` but what do you mean by "coordinate parsing" ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: @Tarass `\tikz\foreach \p in {(0,3),(1,4),(2,3),(3,1)}\fill \p circle [radius=.1];`

Answer (score 3):

uses parentheses { aaa,nnn!} to separate items

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \nn in{{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1},{-1,0}}{
\draw (0,0) -- (\nn);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know that it can be done like this, but that's just what I wanted to avoid (see Andrew Stacey's comment on my question).

Answer (score 1):

Full `foreach` options compatible solution.

The idea is to prepare the loop-string to be `foreach` compatible ie to substitute the significative comma by a phantom caractere before replace the alternative separator by the `foreach`-needed comma. Then in the `foreach` loop itself, to remplace the eventually phantom caractere by a significative comma.

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}          % compatibilité avec Babel
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse,xstring,tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FENewList}{
    D<>{\&}     % phantom substitution caractere
    O{;}        % alternative separator
    m           % input list
    O{\FEList}  % output list
    }{%
    \StrSubstitute{#3}{,}{#1}[#4]
    \StrSubstitute{#4}{#2}{,}[#4]
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\FERestore}{
    D<>{\&}     % phantom substitution caractere
    m           % input string
    }{%
    \StrSubstitute{#2}{#1}{,}[#2]%
    }

\begin{document}

With for \texttt{;} as alternative separator:

\FENewList{sentenceA;se,nt,en,ce,B; sentenceC }
\foreach \x in \FEList {%
\FERestore{\x}
[\x]}

\medskip
With for \texttt{|} as alternative separator:

\FENewList[|]{sentenceA|se,nt,en,ce,B| sentenceC }
\foreach \x in \FEList {%
\FERestore{\x}
[\x]}

\medskip
With for \texttt{foreach} options:

\FENewList[|]{sentenceA|se,nt,en,ce,B| sentenceC }
\foreach \x [count=\i from 1] in \FEList {%
\FERestore{\x}
\noindent\i: [\x]\\}

\FENewList[|]{3|...|5}
\foreach \x in \FEList {%
\FERestore{\x}
\x }

\begin{tikzpicture}

\FENewList{(0,3);(1,4);(2,3);(3,1)}
\foreach \p in \FEList 
{
\FERestore{\p}
\fill \p circle [radius=.1] ;
} 

\end{tikzpicture}
```