# Product folder for latex?

Tags: templates, folders

Is there a product folder template for latex? One were I can insert photos of developed products and a brief description of what it does? I mean ... I tried using google but the best I got were ads for condoms or latex gloves.

Or would you suggest I make my own?

Comment: This seems like a very specialized use which I doubt there is an existing class or package. But it doesn't sound too difficult to create your own. I would probably make it take data from a spreadsheet containing image paths and image descriptions using `datatool`.

Comment: @AlanMunn mmm nice suggestion ... script it and make it simples .. just need to create the style for it. Thank you for your help. Would you like to post it and I'll give you the answer?

Comment: Helps to see what your after however compare your requirements against these requests https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213293/170109 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73677/170109 and hints from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40720/latex-in-industry including http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/en_gb_eclipse_114.pdf